# Nontrivial functionals on $l^\infty$ vanishing on $c_0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

I understood that the dual of $c_0$ is a proper subspace of the dual of $l^\infty$, by Hahn-Banach theorem. But how can I find functionals in $(l^\infty)^*$ vanishing on $c_0$?

Comment: There's a natural nontrivial functional on $c$ that vanishes on $c_0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer What is $c$?

Comment: The space of convergent sequences.

Comment: Do you mean the functional mapping to its limit?

Comment: Yes. Now, using $c_0 \subset c \subset l^\infty$ and Hahn-Banach ...

Comment: Also see this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_limit

Answer (score 2):

Following the approach suggested by Daniel Fischer: define $\phi(x) =\lim x_n$ whenever the limit exists. This defines $\phi$ as a bounded linear functional on a linear space containing $c_0$. By definition $\phi$ vanishes on $c_0$. The Hahn-Banach theorem provides an extension of $\phi$ to an element of $\ell_\infty^*$.